A prepand *Paraphrase* is showig all the time after runnig the code instead of actual paraphrased Sentence
I am creating an URDU TEXT PARAPHRASING tool for my semester.
I have used T5 Model and fine tuned it.
Now when im running this code:
**import torch
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer

# Define your model and tokenizer
model_name = "t5-small"
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def paraphrase_urdu_sentence(sentence, model, tokenizer):
    try:
        # Prepend "paraphrase: " to sentence
        **input_text = "paraphrase: " + sentence**

        # Tokenize input text
        input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors="pt", max_length=128, truncation=True)

        # Generate paraphrased text
        generated_ids = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=128, num_beams=4, early_stopping=True)

        # Decode the generated paraphrased text
        paraphrased_sentence = tokenizer.decode(generated_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

        return paraphrased_sentence

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred during paraphrasing: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    input_sentence = input("Insert Your Text in Urdu: ")
    paraphrased_sentence = paraphrase_urdu_sentence(input_sentence, model, tokenizer)
    if paraphrased_sentence:
        print("Original sentence:", input_sentence)
        print("Paraphrased sentence:", paraphrased_sentence)
    else:
        print("Failed to paraphrase the sentence.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()**

The output should be the paraphrased sentence of what urdu sentence i insert. But its giving me this result:
Insert Your Text in Urdu: آپ کو لگتا ہے کہ آپ کہاں جا رہے ہیں۔
Original sentence: آپ کو لگتا ہے کہ آپ کہاں جا رہے ہیں۔
Paraphrased sentence: Paraphrase:

how to get the paraphrased sentence ? please help its urgennt
I have tried all possible ssolutions suggested by chatgpt nothing works

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is not a place to get urgent help. This isn't my field, but FWIW, it doesn't seem like you've tried any debugging. You might try looking at the intermediate values from your tokenizer and model. And for the sake of a [mre], it looks like you can remove the error handling. If you want more general tips, check out How to ask a good question.
